# How do I get a Firebase-authenticated user to be able to upload a zip file to Cloud Storage for Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to write Dart code that interacts with Firebase so that the code uploads a zip file of photos the user uploaded to Cloud Storage. Here is my code:

```
  final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final zipPath = '${tempDir.path}/trainingData.zip';
  final zipFile = await File(zipPath).writeAsBytes(encodedArchive);

  final storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
  final picRef = storageRef.child("pics.zip");
  final picCollectionsRef =
      storageRef.child("picCollections/pics.zip");
  assert(picRef.name == picCollectionsRef.name);
  assert(picRef.fullPath != picCollectionsRef.fullPath);

  try {
    await picRef.putFile(
        zipFile,
        SettableMetadata(
          contentType: "application/zip",
        ));
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: Zip File not uploaded correctly - $e');
  }

  var downloadURL = await trainingDataRef.getDownloadURL();

  return downloadURL;
```

I keep getting the error message below while testing the app on my iPhone:

```
flutter: Error: Zip File not uploaded correctly - [firebase_storage/unauthorized] User is not authorized to perform the desired action.
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/unauthorized] User is not authorized to perform the desired action.
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:651:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:534:43)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      MethodChannelReference.getDownloadURL (package:firebase_storage_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_reference.dart:45:36)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Here are my Storage security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    match /users/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

I don't want to change the rules to allow anyone who's not authenticated to read and write for security reasons. When I test, the user is fully signed in with Firebase, and their account exists in Firebase.

Why is the user not authorized to upload a zip file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your security rules allow a user to write to a path that starts with `/users/<their user ID>`.

But your code doesn't follow those rules, and tries to write to `/pics.zip`. And since that doesn't match your own rules, the write gets rejected.

To fix this, set your `picRef` to:

```
if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
  final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  final picRef = storageRef.child("/users/$uid/pics.zip");
  ...
}
```